# Dropdown issue in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been trying to get some dropdown on the click of the button but it seems not to be working. Can someone tell me what would be the issue with that.

dashboard.css

```
.dropdown-menu .user-menu {    
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    .user-img{
        width: 100px;
    }   
    .dropdown-item{
        color: #666 !important;
    }
    
}
```

dashboard.html

```
 <div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle no-caret pl-2 pr-2" id="user-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>

      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right rounded-0 mt-3 p-0 box-shadow" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
        <div class="user-menu">
          <div class="user-info text-center p-3">
            <img class="rounded-circle"
              src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/user-icon-trendy-flat-style-260nw-418179865.jpg"
              width="40">
            <p class="mt-1 mb-0">
              Dave
              <br>
              <small>9th Oct 2020</small>
            </p>
          </div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['profile']"><i class="fa fa-user mr-2"></i>{{ 'Profile' }}</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item mb-1" [routerLink]="['/login', {error:'n', id: '1'}]">
            <i class="fa fa-power-off mr-2"></i>{{'LogOut' }}
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    jQuery('#user-menu').on('click', '.nav-item a', function () {
      setTimeout(() => jQuery(this).closest('.dropdown').addClass('show'));
    });
  }
```

imports are like the one below

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
  ]
```

Comment: are you trying to use MatSelect or are you making a custom drop down? can you share your ts file ? of make a stackblitz demo ?

Comment: @Elmehdi I have edited the above code. And I am using the custom dropdown

Comment: Don't use Jquery to manupilate the DOM, angular has built in methodes to do that kind of stuff, or you can use MatSelect, which is an angular material select component  https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Comment: I have created the demo here the MatSelect options doesn't appear on click https://angular-pqqmaw.stackblitz.io

Comment: you shared only the site in you live demo, you didnt share the code base

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i9n8bn?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223210/discussion-between-aayushi-gupta-and-elmehdi).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is import some necessary modules in you app module:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
```

Then you will have to add a form control to your components ts file:

```
toppings = new FormControl();
```

And add it to your template too:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
...
</mat-select>
```

And finally add some styling to styles.css:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.basic-container {
  padding: 30px;
}
.version-info {
  font-size: 8pt;
  float: right;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

Here is a live demo to help you out: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urpdtp)